# Express routing - prevent app.use('/') top-level path middleware from executing when visiting child/nested paths directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm not really sure if the title is descriptive enough, but here is a super simple example.

My site has a public area and a restricted admin area.

`example.com/admin` (admin home page)
`example.com/admin/news` (news page)
`example.com/admin/posts` (posts page)

And because I don't want people who aren't administrators or logged in to be able to access it, I have a simple middleware function to check for cookies.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const authMiddleWere = async (req, res, next) => {
    // pseudo-code, do some cookie validity check here
    console.log(`Route: ${req.url}`)
    if (cookie) {
         next();
    }
};

const adminRouter = require('./routes/private/home');
const newsRouter = require('./routes/private/news');
const postsRouter = require('./routes/private/posts');

app.use('/admin/', authMiddleWere, adminRouter);
app.use('/admin/news', authMiddleWere, newsRouter);
app.use('/admin/posts', authMiddleWere, postsRouter);
```

**/routes/private/home.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res, err) => {
    res.render('private/home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem here is that this `authMiddleWere` function gets called twice when I visit nested paths such as `example.com/admin/news` which shares the same pattern - it's starting with `/admin/.....`.

I can tell that for sure because we are logging the `req.url` in our middleware function so if I go to `example.com/admin` it will log out:

`Route: /`

But if I go to `example.com/admin/news` it will log out both:

`Route: /`
`Route: /news`

So what is causing this and how do I work my way around it? I'm assuming that what I described is the intended behavior of Express.js so I am looking for a way to get around this or (re)structure my code better.

Cheers!

Comment: Try changing the order of your `app.use()` calls so that `/admin/news` and `/admin/posts` were before `/admin/` route

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I just tried and if I do that it logs out only the forward slash `/` and nothing else, both on `admin/news` and `admin/` itself. So I guess it's semi-working but I have literally not idea why.

Comment: Your behavior is actually very weird Express does not match multiple routes at once. Why is your news and posts routes placed after the authMiddleware if should be public?

Comment: @MattiaRasulo those aren't meant to be public routes, they are like news(editor) or posts(editor) but the route prefix in the example is like `example.com/admin/news` where the public version would be `example.com/news`.

Answer (score 1):

Well one way you can fix this is by creating a separate `route` file and splitting everything into a MVC manner. For example:

1. Inside your main **app.js** just create a route pointing to the `/admin` like so:

   `app.use('/admin', authMiddleWere, require('./src/your-route-to-the-file/admin.route'));`
2. Inside the **admin.route** file, call your **controller** like this:

   ```
   const express = require("express");
   const router = express.Router();

   const mainAdminCtrl = require("../controllers/admin.controller");

   router.get("/news", mainAdminCtrl.adminAuthDisplay);

   module.exports = router;
   ```

Where the `const mainAdminCtrl` is your controller and the function `adminAuthDisplay` is your service.

Essentially, you are splitting your functionality in to a dedicated `router`, `controller` and `service` file. So when you try to access the route `/admin`, it will look for any suffix inside the `router` file.

In a case where you want to access the `/news` endpoint, your API will only make the call once.

If this helps, I can expand my explanation further.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the reply. I get the idea behind dedicated `router` in the app.js, however I am a bit ashamed to admit that I don't full understand the whole MVC concept, even though I heard of it many times and even seen some code examples, can't fully understand it in practice. If I am not asking for too much, could you perhaps add a very simple example of how a `../controllers/admin.controller` file would look like? Also, I hope this is not a stupid question but do these file extensions hold any significance at all, or it's just a suffix/separator you are usinging and they are all .js?

Comment: @decho it's not a stupid question. I'll try to answer your question and provide you with some links for additional reading.

Comment: thanks mate, looking forward to it. And if you find yourself too busy, even an external article which can point me out in the right direction would do. Additionally, there is already a good reply provided in the thread already (the regex one), but I can't help but think there is a more elegant approach/solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for your route.

```js
app.use(/\/admin$/, authMiddlewear, authRouter);
```

This will match only routes that end in `admin`.  You may need to handle cases where the route is `/admin/` instead of `/admin`, but iirc, express handles that intelligently.